# How to fix the footer and signature error when flashing partial images files?

Tags: embedded-linux

I have a question, after I have whole built the AOSP source code, it generates couple image files, such as ramdisk.img, recovery.img, system.img, res-package.img,etc .
Right now, I am considering partial flashing my Android Box without formatting all of the system, for keeping some previous data remains. 
Therefore, I just tried to use the command “adb sideload filename.img”, which filename might be ramdisk,recovery, etc.
Then, after I did so, the android system shows the message :
“footer is wrong”
“signature verification failed”
“Installation aborted”
There, what should I correct my command, to make the process correct?
as the figure shows [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtYSq.jpg)
And, my methods to do so is trying to refresh a new system feature, but keep the previous data, such as APPs, or user data, remain, does anybody have other good suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the flash type and file-system you are using, and it is not possible to partially flash in the partition, but you can update the partition.